# How can I get raw <meta-data> values?

Tags: android

I'm using a few `<meta-data>` elements in my `AndroidManifest.xml` to configure a library. I ran into an interesting problem. It looks like the Bundle returned by `PackageItemInfo.metaData` are cast to a type upon parsing.

This is annoying, because it means that a `<meta-data>` element with a value of 1.0 is interpreted as a Float, while 100 is interpreted as an Integer 100, while 010 is interpreted as Integer 10. What I really want is to get the string value that was actually set.

Is there any way to get the original string value of a `<meta-data>` element? The best I can do right now is to prepend all values with a symbol string like XXX, which seems to force the value to be parsed as a String.

Comment: I'd go with quotation marks rather than XXX, but that's just me. I am not aware of a good way for you to get the original text.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you mean something like this? `<meta-data android:name="someName" android:value="'1.0'"/>`

Comment: Yeah. If nothing else, it looks more natural, and should still force the coercion to `String`.